Screen began to blink randomly, when my PC goes to sleep (perhaps after updating linux-firmware)
this problem lasts for two days after this update:
Start-Date: 2024-06-14  10:22:39
Commandline: /usr/bin/apt upgrade -y
Requested-By: ghazan (1000)
Upgrade: linux-firmware:amd64 (20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2, 20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.1), libvte-2.91-common:amd64 (0.76.0-1, 0.76.0-1ubuntu0.1), libvte-2.91-0:amd64 (0.76.0-1, 0.76.0-1ubuntu0.1)
End-Date: 2024-06-14  10:22:46

When I press the power button, which is bound to the Sleep command, the screen begins to blink randomly, becoming black for a moment, then returning back. The console is completely non-responsible, I have to press the power button for 2 seconds to turn the PC off completely.
Ubuntu 24.04 6.8.0-35-generic (64-bit), KDE 5.27.11, framework 5.115.0, Qt 5.15.13, X11.
NVIDIA GeForce GT 1030 with standard Nvidia driver 470:
nvidia-compute-utils-470/noble,now 470.239.06-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-dkms-470/noble,now 470.239.06-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-driver-470/noble,now 470.239.06-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-kernel-common-470/noble,now 470.239.06-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-kernel-source-470/noble,now 470.239.06-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-prime/noble,noble,now 0.8.17.2 all [installed,automatic]
nvidia-settings/noble,now 510.47.03-0ubuntu4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-utils-470/noble,now 470.239.06-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]

WMBR, George Hazan
